# Homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G$ proof

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group. Let $h,k \in G$ and let $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ be defined by $\phi(m,n)=h^mk^n$. Give a necessary and sufficient condition, involving $h$ and $k$, for $\phi$ to be a homomorphism. Prove your condition.

I'm not sure what needs to be done. Any proofs or hints are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: A map $f:G\to H$ is a homomorphism if $f(g_1g_2) = f(g_1)f(g_2)$ for all $g_1, g_2\in G$. Translating this to your map $\phi$, you need to show that
$$\phi((m_1,n_1)+(m_2,n_2)) = \phi(m_1+m_2, n_1+n_2) = h^{m_1+m_2}k^{n_1+n_2}$$
and
$$\phi(m_1,n_1)\phi(m_2,n_2) = h^{m_1}k^{n_1}h^{m_2}k^{n_2}$$
are equal.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What does it mean that

$$\phi(m_1,n_1) \phi(m_2,n_2)= \phi (m_1+m_2, n_1+n_2)\,?$$